# computeRsaSha256Signature() returns Invalid argument: key error when key is public key or rsa private key

Tags: google-apps-script

I need to sign a message using RSA-SHA256 and a public key in my Google Apps Script.

I am trying to use [Utilities.computeRsaSha256Signature(value, key)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#computersasha256signaturevalue-key) for this, but I just get an `Invalid argument: key` error.

For the purpose of this question I have generated a key-pair like this:

```
openssl genrsa -out private.pem 32
openssl rsa -in private.pem -out public.pem -outform PEM -pubout
```

My script looks like this:

```js
function test() {
  var privKey = "-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\nMCwCAQACBQC6fs8xAgMBAAECBQCxyL35AgMA3ecCAwDXJwICKLcCAnF9AgIbnA==\n-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\n";
  var pubKey = "-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\nMCAwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEBBQADDwAwDAIFALp+zzECAwEAAQ==\n-----END PUBLIC KEY-----\n";
  Utilities.computeRsaSha256Signature("value", pubKey); 
  Utilities.computeRsaSha256Signature("value", privKey);
}
```

When I run this I get an `Invalid argument: key` error on the first call to `computeRsaSha256Signature`.

The error suggests there is something wrong with they key, but I can't figure out what the problem is. I've tried with both the public and the private key and I've tried to strip the newlines but everything fails with the same message.

My code looks very similar to the example in the documentation so I'm not sure what I am doing wrong.

How can `Utilities.computeRsaSha256Signature()` be used successfully?

Comment: Try to check this [github](https://github.com/Spencer-Easton/Apps-Script-GSApp-Library), it explained here the Google Service Account Library for Apps Script. It is stated here that this is an improved version of Google service account library for Google Apps Script. This makes use of the new Utilities.computeRsaSha256Signature(value, key). I've added the ability to batch request tokens for users in your domain. If you need to request a token for your script itself add the client_email as a user.Check also this [issue](https://plus.sandbox.google.com/106009755685055488206/posts/bYuPM6MGwsU).

Comment: Thanks @KENdi, the Google+ post was especially helpful. It seems like computeRsaSha256Signature() only supports PRIVATE KEY signatures (not PRIVATE RSA KEY). Unfortunately I need to do a PUBLIC KEY signature which this doesn't seem to support.

Comment: No prob. I'm glad that I help you even though it is a small thing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Keys starting with BEGIN PRIVATE KEY have a different format than the ones with BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY.

I was starting from a key in the "RSA" format but the computeRsaSha256Signature needs a key in the non-RSA format.

You can convert from the latter to the former with:

openssl pkcs8 -topk8 -inform pem -in private.pem -outform pem -nocrypt -out newPrivate.pem

Source:
https://plus.google.com/106009755685055488206/posts/bYuPM6MGwsU

Comment: Thanks, I've confirmed that signing with a PRIVATE KEY (instead of RSA PRIVATE KEY) and that works. So this answers my question, unfortunately it doesn't solve my problem since I need to do a PUBLIC KEY signature which doesn't seem to be supported.

Answer (score 0):

There are at least three different types of keys that can be used when doing a rsa sha256 signature:

```
BEGIN PRIVATE KEY
BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY
BEGIN PUBLIC KEY
```

As indicated by the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36700930/1730966) and based on my own testing it seems like `computeRsaSha256Signature` only supports the `BEGIN PRIVATE KEY` type.

As the accepted answer explains it is possible to convert a `RSA PRIVATE KEY` to a `PRIVATE KEY` however when all you have is the public key it's more complicated.

In this scenario an external library like [JSEncrypt](https://github.com/travist/jsencrypt) can be useful. However this assumes that the `window` and `navigator` objects exist which they do in normal JavaScript environments but doesn't in Google Apps Scripts.

But with [some modification](https://gist.github.com/nibarius/9d102f803814a932c18ecba00cfc1249) it's possible to get JSEncrypt to work good enough with Google Apps Scripts to sign messages using a public key.

Comment: Would I be able to use your modifications to sign with a private key for github commit signing using a PGP Private key?

Comment: I'm not sure if it works or not, but feel free to try.