# Gate.io google app script "INVALID_SIGNATURE","message":"Signature mismatch"

Tags: google-apps-script, cryptocurrency

I am trying to do a request to Gate.io cryptocurrency market and getting this error.
`{"label":"INVALID_SIGNATURE","message":"Signature mismatch"}`
I have managed to find a way to correctly encrypt all the parameters(my output is the same as they presented in their documentation), however, when I add a real secret key I got this error.
Please see the screenshot:
the right-hand side is a signature from their doc, in the GAS log you see my output so these are the same however when I add real timestamp and my real secret then it doesn't work
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d4OqQ.png).

Here is the fetch request I am using:

```
function getDateIo() {
var key = "xxx"
var sec = "xxx"
var timestamp = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000)

var a = {"contract":"BTC_USD","type":"limit","size":100,"price":6800,"time_in_force":"gtc"}
a = JSON.stringify(a)
var body = {"text":"t-123456","currency_pair":"ETH_BTC","type":"limit","account":"spot","side":"buy","iceberg":"0","amount":"1","price":"5.00032","time_in_force":"gtc","auto_borrow":false}
body = JSON.stringify(body)
console.log(body)

   var requestPayload = Utilities.computeDigest(Utilities.DigestAlgorithm.SHA_512, "")
     requestPayload = requestPayload.map(function(e) {
    var v = (e < 0 ? e + 256 : e).toString(16);
    return v.length == 1 ? "0" + v : v;
}).join("");

console.log(requestPayload)

var meth = 'GET'
var pat = '/api/v4/futures/orders'

var sign = meth + "\n" + pat + "\n" + "contract=BTC_USD&status=finished&limit=50" + "\n" + requestPayload + "\n" + timestamp;

console.log(sign)

  var signature = Utilities.computeHmacSignature(Utilities.MacAlgorithm.HMAC_SHA_512, sign, sec);
  signature = signature.map(function(e) {
    var v = (e < 0 ? e + 256 : e).toString(16);
    return v.length == 1 ? "0" + v : v;
}).join("");
 
    var params = {
        'method': "get",
        'headers': {
                      'Accept': 'application/json', 
                      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                       'KEY': key, 
                       'Timestamp': timestamp,
                       'SIGN': signature,
                       
                      },
        // 'body': body,
        'muteHttpExceptions': true,
    };

   var data = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://api.gateio.ws/api/v4/futures/orders?contract=BTC_USD&status=finished&limit=50", params);

}
```

Thanks for any advice

Comment: Your  signature is obviously wrong. I assume you use an invalid key format when creating the signature, but cannot tell without seeing the code

Comment: I added the whole code could you please take a look?

Comment: I think this is wrong: 
var requestPayload = Utilities.computeDigest(Utilities.DigestAlgorithm.SHA_512, "")

You probably want to compute digest on the payload, probably the body :
var requestPayload = Utilities.computeDigest(Utilities.DigestAlgorithm.SHA_512, body)

Comment: this was just an example to show that the code is working because the output is the same as in the Gate.io doc. However when I used my real secret key and hash request body, then it doesn't work.

Comment: Check the key you are using. This may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36614051/computersasha256signature-returns-invalid-argument-key-error-when-key-is-publ