# Invalid argument: key error in Utilities.computeRsaSha256Signature

Tags: google-apps-script, cryptography, add-on, pem, google-workspace-add-ons

I tried the below code in my code.gs. I'm getting an error.

```
  let privatekey = 'IcA3+ZwPmUMtAou4f9hJMg==';
  var key = `-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\n${privatekey}\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n`;
  console.log(key)

  var signature = Utilities.computeRsaSha256Signature("this is my input", key);
  Logger.log(signature);
```

In the console I'm getting the key:

```
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
IcA3+ZwEmUMtAou4f9hHMg==
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
```

Error: **Exception: Invalid argument: key**

I have attached the ss of the error.
Can anyone help me with this error? why it's coming?
[image: Error Image]

Comment: Can you share how you're generating your private key?

Comment: I'm not generating the key.  I have one key.  I have updated the code.

Comment: Apologies. What I meant was, where did you generate the private key that you're using? A reason why I'm asking for that is because I found this [Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51989469) on how to generate one and another [Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36614051) with a similar issue as this.

Comment: Yes, I had checked. My key is generated somewhere else. I want to use this in google app script methods. If it's not possible then can you suggest any documentation on how to generate key?

Comment: You can follow the first post I linked to the question `on how to generate key`, as there are options in the answer on how to do so. The second one has the same error that you're getting, explaining that this is happening because keys have `different format`.

Comment: That's not a PKCS8 private key, and it's not an RSA private in any format. It might be a secret key for a symmetric algorithm like AES or a Mac algorithm like HMAC.

Comment: As James mentioned already, that doesn't look like a proper RSA key. It's a 128 Bit value. You can't just take a key or string, add a header and footer and treat it as an RSA key. You need to generate a RSA-key pair.